# How can I persist a login token in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, okhttp

I feel like I must be missing something simple here.
I am trying to return the login token so that it can be used throughout the application.  The login token prints to the console just fine within the onResponse method, but when I try to return that token, I can't.

```
lateinit var authToken: String

    fun getAuthToken(user: User): String {
        sendPostRequest(user.username, user.password)
        return authToken
    }


    fun sendPostRequest(userName: String, password: String): String {


        var rb = MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("username", userName)
            .addFormDataPart("password", password)
            .build()

        val request = Request.Builder().url(URL_AUTH_ADDRESS).post(rb).build()
        Log.d("request", request.toString())
        val client = OkHttpClient()

        var responseAuth = ""
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {

            override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?){
                val body = response?.body()?.string()
                authToken = response?.body()?.string()!!
                Log.d("usersAuthToken", body)
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
                authToken = "fail"
            }

        })
        Log.d("outside method", "resp: " + authToken)
        return authToken


    }
```

As shown above, this will crash stating that authToken is never initialized.  But when I remove the return statements, the `Log.d("usersAuthToken", body)` statement prints the token like it should.

The end goal is to have that authToken persisted throughout the app after logging in. I'm very green in the field of Kotlin so if there is a better way that I am missing, PLEASE let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to return the token before the asynchronous function in `sendPostRequest` finishes. You should change your `getAuthToken` and `sendPostRequest` functions to the following:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

lateinit var authToken: String

    fun getAuthToken(user: User): String {
        runBlocking {
            sendPostRequest(user.username, user.password)
        }
        return authToken
    }


    suspend fun sendPostRequest(userName: String, password: String): String {


        var rb = MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("username", userName)
            .addFormDataPart("password", password)
            .build()

        val request = Request.Builder().url(URL_AUTH_ADDRESS).post(rb).build()
        Log.d("request", request.toString())
        val client = OkHttpClient()

        var responseAuth = ""
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {

            override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?){
                val body = response?.body()?.string()
                authToken = response?.body()?.string()!!
                Log.d("usersAuthToken", body)
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
                authToken = "fail"
            }

        })
        Log.d("outside method", "resp: " + authToken)
        return authToken


    }
```

`suspend` is used to specify whether it is an asynchronous function and `runBlocking` is used to make the thread wait until the function has finished running.

You should also add the following to your `build.gradle` file to add the `coroutines` dependency:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.2'
}
```

And make sure that you use the latest Kotlin version:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
}
```

Make sure that you have either jcenter() or mavenCentral() in the list of repositories:

```
repository {
    jcenter()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response but I'm still getting the same error. `kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property authToken has not been initialized
        at edu.cmich.inspector_applet.Helpers.loginHelper.sendPostRequest(loginHelper.kt:58)
        at edu.cmich.inspector_applet.Helpers.loginHelper$getAuthToken$1.invokeSuspend(loginHelper.kt:25)`

Comment: Mmmm ok. Did try logging ```Log.d("usersAuthToken", authToken)``` instead of ```body```? Are you getting the same response in that case?